# How to convert Wpf Page application to dll?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I write Page application with WPF as exe project.
But when i change type of project to Class library- i get many errors:
`Library project file cannot specify ApplicationDefinition element`,
`The name InitializeComponent does not exist in the current context`.

How to convert Page exe project to dll?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried, you can delete App.Xaml and rebuild will succeed.